# Configuring iptables for guest WLAN in DD-WRT

Tags: wireless-networking, iptables, dd-wrt

I'm constantly failing to get a guest WLAN in DD-WRT working. I can connect to the second SSID and get an IP address of the second DHCP server range. But I cannot connect to the internet.

I followed this two tutorials:

- [Multiple WLANs - Separating the WLAN's](http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Multiple_WLANs#Separating_the_WLAN.27s)
- [DD-WRT Guest Wireless](http://www.alexlaird.com/2013/03/dd-wrt-guest-wireless/)

Both tell me to put this

```
iptables -t nat -I POSTROUTING -o `get_wanface` -j SNAT --to `nvram get wan_ipaddr`
iptables -I FORWARD -i br1 -m state --state NEW -j ACCEPT
iptables -I FORWARD -i br1 -o br0 -m state --state NEW -j DROP
```

into the Administration -> Command and hit 'Save Firewall'.

But this seems to have no effect.

Any ideas what's wrong?

Comment: Run this command, "iptables -L -v" (Administration | Commands | (paste) | Run) and post the output.